# Waiting for incoming serial communication data Python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to make a program which run serial communication with another program in python. In my program, I want to wait a specific incoming data. So far, I have successfully done it with this command :

```
while ser.read(length)!= incoming_data:
    pass
```

But the incoming_data has various possibility. I want to check what data is coming and do a specific task for each incoming data. In tera term macro I can use this code:

```
wait data1 data2
if result = 1 then .....
if result = 2 then ....
```

How can I do the same thing in python serial? because each data has different length. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could buffer the incoming data and then check for matches. Something like

```
buf = ''
while 1:
    buf += ser.read(1)
    if buf == data1:
        # do stuff
        buf = ''
    elif buf == data2:
        # do something else
        buf = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you need a terminating character of some kind to indicate the end of the message. Typically the newline character is used (`\n`). pyserial has a method [`readline()`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike.readline) which will read until it reaches a newline character and then return that data.